# Changing the flux through a coil by changing the current through it

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

My textbook says:

> The magnetic flux through a circuit or a coil (call it $A$) can be changed in a number of different ways (one of which I give here):
>
> - By changing current in the neighbouring coil or by changing current in the coil ($A$) itself.

I don't understand how the flux through $A$ changes by changing the current in $A$ itself. Changing the number of turns in $A$ will change the flux through $A$, but will it change the current too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic flux through a coil is proportional to the current flowing through it. Thus the magnetic flux through coil A changes with the current flowing through it.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the formula for magnetic field then you will find that is the directly proportional to the current.

[image]

So if the current increases the magnetic field of a current element increases and thus the magnetic flux increases.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the magnetic field *of* $A$ is directly proportional to the current flowing through it. But the flux *through* $A$ is due to the magnetic field of the *other* coil.

Comment: Changing current changes flux around the current carrying element. So you change the current in the other coil so the flux in the space around it increases. I suggest that you take a look the magnetic field lines generated by a current carrying coil.

Comment: But changing the current passing through $A$ wouldn't affect the flux through $A$ by the magnetic field of the other coil. That's the question.

Comment: If there are two such solenoids, and if we change the turn density $n$ in one of the solenoids, will it affect the flux through this solenoid (with changed turn density) due to the magnetic field of the other solenoid?

Comment: No....if the current in the other coil is constant..